# Standard error of average estimate

Tags: estimation, standard-error

If I have multiple estimates, e.g. a set of regression coefficients or estimated means, each estimate associated with a standard error. I can easily average them to get an average estimate. However, how do I compute the average standard error based on the individual estimates and individual standard errors?

Comment: Do you want to assume that your estimators are independent (computed on independent data)? Whether averaging is any good depends on some not given details by the way, e.g., whether different estimators were computed on samples of the same size. Note that if you have one estimator with a small standard error and others with much larger standard errors, the average of the estimators may be worse than the single estimator with lowest standard error.

Comment: To give you information where I am coming from: Damodaran (NYU Prof in Finance) says, that one can take the average of several CAPM (i.e. univariate regression) betas of similar firms and get the standard error of this average by: avg(beta)/root(number of betas). See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qKy5UGcvWaw&list=PLUkh9m2BorqnKWu0g5ZUps_CbQ-JGtbI9&index=5 (minute 9 to see the slide).

Comment: You probably mean avg(se(beta)). This assumes independence and that the standard errors of all the estimators are the same.

Comment: Sorry, yes you are right. I tried to find another resource that states this holds or derives this. Could you point me to one? Also - this assumes that the SEs are the same? Does this mean that this assumes that the SE of all the estimators is equal to the average across the estimators?

Comment: See, if you want to know what exactly Damodaran means, you've got to ask him not us. The assumption is that the *true* SEs are the same, and then one can use the average of the observed ones to estimate that (although that's not necessarily optimal). In case the SEs are different and you have independence, the formula requires the square root of the avg. variance, which isn't quite the same as avg. se (only if the ses/variances are all the same). That would be a more standard formula. Maybe Damodaran meant that and wrote it down wrongly. (But then it isn't necessarily good to average.)